# Localizar campos em string com expressões regulares em python

Tags: python, regex

Estou fazendo login em um dispositivo e dando um ifconfig nele, as informações geradas são:

```
['ifconfig']
['>ifconfig']
['br0       Link encap', 'Ethernet  HWaddr A4:33:D7:53:5E:08  ']
['          inet addr', '192.168.15.1  Bcast:192.168.15.255  Mask:255.255.255.0']
['          inet6 addr', ' 2804:431:c7c7:6528:a633:d7ff:fe53:5e08/64 Scope:Global']
['          inet6 addr', ' fe80::a633:d7ff:fe53:5e08/64 Scope:Link']
['          UP BROADCAST RUNNING ALLMULTI MULTICAST  MTU', '1500  Metric:1']
['          RX packets', '6563071 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0']
['          TX packets', '7874170 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0']
['          collisions', '0 txqueuelen:0 ']
['          RX bytes', '714777540 (681.6 MiB)  TX bytes:886124155 (845.0 MiB)']
['']
['br0', '0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr A4:33:D7:53:5E:08  ']
['          inet addr', '192.168.249.1  Bcast:192.168.249.3  Mask:255.255.255.252']
['          UP BROADCAST RUNNING ALLMULTI MULTICAST  MTU', '1500  Metric:1']
```

Dentro destes campos preciso buscar somente algumas informações.

Fiz assim, porém não está funcionando:

```
for chave in saida:
    #print(chave)
    aux = chave.split(":",1)
    print(aux)
    if aux[0] == 'br0       Link encap':
        saida_json['MAC'] = aux[1].strip()
    elif aux[0] == '          inet6 addr':
        saida_json['IPV6'] = aux[1].strip()
```

Answer (score 1):

Cara se você deseja pegar o endereço IP e o MAC de um dispositivo, recomendo usar uma ferramenta que faça isso. Exemplo a lib como a [netifaces](https://pypi.org/project/netifaces/), precisa instalar ela com `pip`, um exemplo

```
import netifaces as ni
ni.ifaddresses('eth0')
ip = ni.ifaddresses('eth0')[ni.AF_INET][0]['addr']
mac = ni.ifaddresses('eth0')[ni.AF_LINK][0]['addr']
```

Ou então se vc ainda prefere usar regex, acho que uma abordagem melhor seria

```
import os
import re

ipv4 = re.search(re.compile(r'(?<=inet )(.*)(?=\/)', re.M), os.popen('ip addr show eth0').read()).groups()[0]
ipv6 = re.search(re.compile(r'(?<=inet6 )(.*)(?=\/)', re.M), os.popen('ip addr show eth0').read()).groups()[0]
```

Comment: gostei da resosta (+1) mas parece-me que nem sempre haverá "eth0"...

Comment: Concordo que é um exemplo bem simples. Mas no enunciado dele ele usa tbm  `hardcoded` a `br0`. Com a `netifaces` para listar todas as interfaces, basta `netifaces.interfaces()` que retorna uma lista de intercafes.